# Angular 10 - best way to add custom css url?

Tags: css, angular, angular9, scss-lint, angular10

We have styles.scss (base css file) and also providing option to load custom css url so custom can change their logo or colors...

Below is the requirement:

if custom URL is not available then it should load base css file
if custom URL loading is failed then it should load base css file
if custom URL is provided then it should load custom url and render the UI

I tried to option to add custom css in stylsheet in index.html but it is not loading as expected. I am getting base css is loading first and then custom css so i can see transition from base css to custom css.

how we can load only custom css when i have custom URL ?

Please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried compiling it with the --aot flag?

If that doesn't work, you could use some type of semantic nomenclature (like maintainableCSS) so that you could just give different html class names to your elements so that they are only referenced by your component's css stylesheet instead of style.css